# Must constructors of child classes mirror their parent's constructor exactly in java?

Tags: java, inheritance

Java noobie here.
I'm trying to create a constructor for a Child class that inherits from a complete class called Parent. The child class has a few properties that the Parent class does not, but when I add these to the constructor, I get an error:

> error: constructor Parent in class Parent cannot be applied to given
>   types;

I'm not sure whether my syntax is wrong, or whether I've got the principle of the matter confused. Any help with either would be much appreciated.

My code:

```
public class Parent {
  public String name;
  public int id;
  public String type;

  public Parent(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.type = "not endangered";
  }

}
```

And, separately,

```
  public Child(String name, String health, String age) {
    //perhaps I need to declare something like Parent(name) here first? This doesn't seem to work, either;
    this.name = name;
    this.health = health;
    this.age = age;
    this.endangered = true;
    this.type = "endangered";
  }

}
```

Comment: [Many similar questions](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+error:+constructor+in+class+cannot+be+applied+to+given+types)

Comment: If in the future if you want to avoid having your question closed as a duplicate, then when asking what is likely to be a common question you will want to provide links to the previous canonical questions of a similar nature and explain in fairly good detail why their answers don't answer what you're asking and how your question is truly unique.

Comment: What you need to add to the child constructor is a call to `super` passing in the name field, `super(name);` but again, any search on your error message would tell you this.